# Get a value from a config file (/etc/network/interfaces) for an init.d script

Tags: bash, configuration-files

I want to get the network address (192.168.42.) from my /etc/network/interfaces file.
I am only interested for the interface "wlan0" and it would be good to have a check whether the section below exists.

In the example interfaces file of "wlan0" the IP adress is 192.168.42.1. For the init.d script I subsequently want to replace the last byte (*.1) with *.255. So the IP will should be: "192.168.42.255"

Does someone know how to read the address of the network from such a file for a init.d script and to replace the last byte?

```
iface wlan0 inet static
  address 192.168.42.1
  netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Currently, I just know how to check whether the file exists.

```
# Check for existence of needed config file and read it
test -r $CONFIGF || { echo "$CONFIGF not existing";
    if [ "$1" = "stop" ]; then exit 0;
    else exit 6; fi; }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `awk` for this, since it is quite readable:

```
awk -v par="wlan0" '
      /^iface/ && $2==par {f=1}
      /^iface/ && $2!=par {f=0}
      f && /^\s*address/ {print $2; f=0}' file
```

#### Explanation

- `-v par="wlan0"` provide the interface name you want to check
- `/^iface/ && $2==par {f=1}` if a line starts with `iface` and the 2nd value is the given interface name, set a flag.
- `/^iface/ && $2!=par {f=0}` if a line starts with `iface` and the 2nd value is NOT the given interface name, unset the flag.
- `f && /^\s*address/ {print $2; f=0}` if the flag is set and a line starts with `address`, print the second black, being it the IP. Then, reset the counter (thanks [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258523/etan-reisner) for the idea).

Note this checks that the lines are not commented.

If you want to replace the last `.1` with `.255`, you can replace the last condition to something like:

```
f && /^\s*address/ {ip=$2; sub(".1$", ".255", ip); print ip; f=0}
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

#### Test

Given a file based on your input:

```
$ cat a
iface eth0 inet static
address xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
netmask 255.255.255.0

iface wlan0 inet static
address 192.168.42.1
netmask 255.255.255.0

iface eth1 inet static
address yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
netmask 255.255.255.0
```

It returns:

```
$ awk -v par="wlan0" '/^iface/ && $2==par {f=1} /^iface/ && $2!=par {f=0} f && /^\s*address/ {print $2; f=0}' a
192.168.42.1
```

And replacing the last portion of the ip:

```
$ awk -v par="wlan0" '/^iface/ && $2==par {f=1} /^iface/ && $2!=par {f=0} f && /^\s*address/ {ip=$2; sub(".1$", ".255", ip); print ip; f=0}' a
192.168.42.255
```

Comment: You probably want to reset `f` on blank lines or put awk in paragraph mode or something since this will print the address of every interface listed after `wlan0` in the file I think.

Comment: you are absolutely right, edited with this idea. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a nice way to remove the last number from the IP and replace it with the broadcast address. E.g. like: 
192.168.42.1 ==> 192.168.42.255

Comment: @dgrat this looks like a new question. Update your question with a proper explanation of it so we can guess how this should be implemented.

Comment: The answer helped me already a lot. I updated the question. Thanks in advance. I really lack admin skills :)

Comment: The reset only happens when an interface has an address. It is possible for interfaces to not have addresses.

Comment: @galgalesh ok, good to know. Thanks for your edit addressing this!